# Working with an EEA family permit in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, immigration, resident-permit, family

I’m not sure about what I have to do in order to work in UK with an EEA family permit in UK.

- Can a non European work in UK with an EEA family permit?
- Can I work immediately?
- What is required in order to work in UK with this permit?
- What are the rights with an EEA family permit?
- How does the health insurance work for a non European? Do I have to buy one?
- I heard that we need some kind of number to give to the employer in order to work. Do you know what is that?

Comment: Yes you have the right to work, immediately and without special permission (even the number in question is not a *requirement* to have the right to work: it's the other way around, you must have the right to work to get it, cf. https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number).

Comment: The UK healthcare system is not primarily based on insurance (not even a statutory single-payer insurance) but on providing care directly. If you do succeed in getting an EEA family permit and moving with your boyfriend, you should be covered by the NHS by virtue of being a UK resident.